# Is there any benefit to using sprite sheets in Java with awt?

Tags: java, image, performance, awt, sprite-sheet

I am aware that [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7480/28924) addresses the issue for flash and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473151/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-sprite-sheet-compared-to-an-image-sequence) addresses the issue vaguely for miscellaneous rendering engines like OpenGL. The way the latter asserts the superiority of sprite sheets by stating that adjusting the UV's of an image is easier than loading in a whole new image.

The way I am currently loading sprites from an image is shown below

```
BufferedImage spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("res/sprite.png"));
Image desiredImage = spriteSheet.getSubimage(0, 0, 16, 16);
```

This doesn't adjust the UV's of `spriteSheet`, it creates a copy of the desired section of the image, which seems like something that would suck up a lot more memory.

Is there a better way to use sprites? Is it more effective to use sprites or just load the images individually in this situation?

Comment: *"would suck up a lot more memory."* - Loading separate sprites is likely to use more memory in the short term, as the image is decoded and convert into the internal representation of the image object used by Java.  Sub imaging in this way would, generally, be quicker and probably produce a small memory load (as opposed to reading each file) as the image is already in the memory model used by Java, but yes, it will create a new copy of the section of the parent image. The real answer will depend on what you intend to use it for.  If it's short lived, this might be preferrable

Comment: Sub imaging is also faster, but will still come down to how the image is been used.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm drawing them to a `JPanel` by using `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to call `g.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)`.

Comment: I thinking more along the line how how long the sprites might stay in memory

Comment: @MadProgrammer In general, they are organizing groups of images, not a single animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, `BufferedImage.getSubimage(...)` *will not* create a new copy of image data. It will only be a (live) view of the "parent" image. This is very fast and cheap compared to actually cloning the data array. So, I'd say it makes perfectly sense to use a sprite sheet in this way.

Any changes made to the parent image will be reflected in the subimages and vice versa. From the javadoc:

> Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image.

In other words, only a small wrapper around the data array is created for each subimage instance. The easiest way to verify this, would be to just try drawing over one of the subimages and see that changes are reflected.

As @MadProgrammer points out, loading a large image once is likely to be faster and more memory efficient than loading many small images.

However, there are some gotchas:

- A larger image will need a larger continuous block of memory. This might be a problem in a Java VM that has been running for a while, as free memory gets fragmented (probably less a problem in a modern VMs, and no problem at all, if you load your image once, early in your game).
- After you have created a subimage, the memory for the parent image cannot be freed until the subimage is freed (because of the shared data array). If this is not what you want, you need to manually create copies of the subimages.